# How to combine select distinct and order by a non-selected attribute or any alternative way?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How to combine select distinct and order by a non-selected attribute or any alternative way?

I have a table called message

```
+----+------+-----------+-------------+
| id | body | sender_id | receiver_id |
+----+------+-----------+-------------+
| 10 | ...  |         1 |           2 |
| 28 | ...  |         1 |           3 |
| 29 | ...  |         2 |           1 |
| 30 | ...  |         2 |           1 |
| 31 | ...  |         1 |           2 |
| 32 | ...  |         3 |           1 |
| 37 | ...  |         1 |          47 |
+----+------+-----------+-------------+
```

Is there a way to select a unique list of the latest receiver_ids (ORDER BY id DESC) and limiting the list by 10 items ?

The result should be

```
+-------------+
| receiver_id |
+-------------+
|          47 |
|           1 |
|           2 |
|           3 |
+-------------+
```

As we know:

```
SELECT DISTINCT receiver_id FROM message ORDER BY id
```

Is not a valid sql because the id attribute must be in the select list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
select receiver_id from 
(select receiver_id, max(id) max_id from message group by receiver_id) ilv 
order by max_id desc limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "order by not-selected attribute" means.  But the basic query can be handled using `where` and a subquery (or a `join` and explicit aggregation):

```
select m.receiver_id
from message m
where m.id = (select max(m2.id) from message m2 where m2.sender = m.sender)
order by id desc;
```

I am guessing that the ordering criterion is `id desc`.

Comment: I think the sub-query can't access an attribute from the outer query.

Comment: @faresoft  . . . Why would you think something that is simply not true.  Basically, almost every database supports correlated subqueries.  They are an important part of the language.  A simple place to start learning is in the MySQL documentation itself:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 10
        a.receiver_id
FROM    ( SELECT    id ,
                    receiver_id ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY receiver_id ORDER BY id DESC ) [rank]
          FROM      message
        ) a
WHERE   a.rank = 1
ORDER BY a.id DESC

This is t-sql query

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT receiver_id
FROM message
group by receiver_id
ORDER BY id DESC
limit 10
```

This will give you distinct receiver_id values, ordered by receiver ID.
MySql seems to be consistent in ordering, regardless of the row limit.

You can play with a similar example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/35918

Comment: The "distinct" reorder the results

Comment: @faressoft: updated and made the query use group by. Initially didn't consider the row limit constraint.

Comment: It is an invalid sql statement.

Comment: It is valid, but does not return the result in the right order (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0789/1)

Comment: Well, that's obvious. I've now made it sort in descending order (which I had forgotten to specify)